# autoindent don't work in php file

Tags: vim

When I edit php file,the autoindent setting just don't work.It works in js css and any other files.Only in php file,I need to turn autoindent on manually.Here's my [vimrc](https://github.com/BirdEggegg/vimrc/blob/master/vimrc).
I found after I run `:source ~/.vimrc` autoindent is on.I am confused.

Comment: I have a basic configuration and the indentation works. Maybe the problem comes from the line `Plugin '2072/PHP-Indenting-for-VIm'`. Can you disable it ? Is your test file actually contains php ?

Comment: after disable the plugin,still not work.and my test file is php file.use `:set filetype?`,it also says php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indentation script for PHP files, which is provided by default in vim installation, disables `autoindent` explicitly. It also defines `GetPhpIndent()` function, which it uses to do indentation (see `indentexpr`). That function, in turn, is using `b:PHP_default_indenting` variable to decide how many `shiftwidth` will be added to the indentation and by default it is 0.

If you put

```
let b:PHP_default_indenting = 1
```

in your `.vimrc`, the indentation should start working.